# Is it possible to make git ignore UTF-8 BOM when commit?

Tags: git

I have some UTF-8 encoded text file, is it possible to make git to ignore the UTF-8 BOMs when commit? I know git can auto convert different EOLs (`"\r"`, `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`), but can I make git to ignore the BOMs and only commit the file contents?

PS: I already have a tool to remove text files's UTF-8 BOMs, but it's inconvenient, I have to run it every time before I commit, it will be more convenient if there's a way to make git to auto process the BOMs.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Some Windows text editors have the annoying habit of adding the BOM where "missing" on every save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`pre-commit` hook](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/), which is designed for such a purpose.

Comment: It seems like a solution. But I can't write a script to do the work for now. I'll look into it later.

Comment: @EFanZh as you already have a tool that removes the BOMs, the script should consists of a trivial invocation of the tool.